# In search for PEAR HTML_Table replacement

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have some trouble using PEAR HTML_Table (Strict error, bug seems still open).

I want to find a standard way to create HTML output that produces a table from associative arrays (where the key shall be in col#1, value in col#2 if nested it shall make a sub-table, if possible, if not, just indent the sub-key.

Also, if possible, would be nice to have formatting means like alteranting rows and hover of lines, but that's obviously an option.

Significant: I would like to have "plain php code" rather than an extension that requires a dll due to update restrictions on the PHP server I use.

Any hints / tips for me to do this without crunching my own code?

Answer (score 0):

There are lot's of table generation classes out there.

https://github.com/search?l=PHP&q=datagrid&type=Repositories

Just to name a few:

- https://github.com/donquixote/cellbrush
- https://github.com/naomik/htmlgen
- https://github.com/intrip/bootstrap-table-generator
- DataGrid Classes for Zend Framework - http://modules.zendframework.com/?query=datagrid

Comment: Great! Thanks!, have not thought about searching GitHub, which is, of course the logical thing. Must have been blind ...

Comment: @Jens, thanks for linking my library. It was unmaintained for awhile, but I needed it again, so I just gave it a big refresh. ^__^